# Using PHP to fetch and Image from Facebook Graph API imagecreatefromstring()

Tags: php, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to use php to fetch an image from facebook using the 
`file_get_contents` and `imagecreatefromstring` functions in php
But starting from today these both were not working. Facebook displays a page to "**update your browser**" when the link is opened via `file_get_contents`.

A sample image url: `http://graph.facebook.com/943781599119424/picture?width=25&height=25`

I used curl to fetch the image. it works for some time then facebook returns null but no longer does 
What can I do to fix this??

Comment: could you please provide some code? its hard to tell where this is going wrong.

Comment: This is probably a result of the frantic changes Facebook is now making to try and save their stock price :) Calling this URL directly in the browser now pops up the download dialog instead of directly showing the image, that has never happened before. Using the given URL as image `src` still works though. That you store those images in your system is probably something Facebook tries to prevent now, but if you need it, I would perhaps first of all try whether making this a proper HTTPS Graph API URL including an API version and passing along a valid access token changes anything.

Comment: Likely related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/560392384345729/

Comment: @CBroe I tried various solutions.. Using the latest chrome user agent works for a while. Then after some usage facebook returns null for the ip. Is there a workaround? even using graph API I get the same reult

Comment: Is there a need to actually store those images in your system? Just using the URL as image `src` should still work fine.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, in fact, there is, I use PHP to get the image. A workaround was to use the user-agent of chrome browser. But after a while we only get a emply response using that.

Comment: “After a while” means what exactly? How many of those requests are you making, and in what frequency?

Comment: @CBroe After a while means after a number of requests. I've lot of users and like after 500 - 1000 requests (approx)