# Change in facebook photo's api getting https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser?_rdr

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Hey I a getting https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser?_rdr whenever i am trying to download data from within my application in unity. This seems to be a very recent development since it was working till last week.

The major change is that now Facebook has started to download the photo on to the client compared to loading it in the browser only. I was using Unity's WWW class to download the image.

Any idea how we can fix this issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49513264/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49513735/1427878

Comment: There are currently multiple related issues. Suggest you go follow the bugs reports in the developer section for updates and details. // Facebook is making changes all over the place right now, in a state that seems to be close enough to be called “panic” ...

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516674/7542765

Answer (score 0):

This was more of a temporary issue. Facebook has fixed the issue from their side. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261587761048160/